# how to configure SMTP server with .net domain instead of .com domain

Tags: sharepoint-2010, smtp

I have two Questions...

1. how to  to configure SMTP server with .net domain instead of .com domain in SharePoint 2010 ?      please provide a steps to do this.
2. how  to configure email server with my SharePoint 2010 list, means i want to send alert or mail is any changes in list. please provide suitable steps.

Thanking You !
ravikant

Answer (score 0):

1. The "From" E-mail Address is specified in the Central Admin Console under System Settings -> E-Mail and Text Messages -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings.  If you need to specify a seperate "From" address for the server default this can be done, but must be done so programmically and within the contents of a workflow. There is an example of how to do this [here](http://perrystechblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-custom-workflow-action-in.html).
2. To configure notifications of additions or changes to a list I use SharePoint designer and workflows.  You can configure a workflow to automatically initiate on either a creation or modification of a list item and then create a Send Email action within the workflow to route the message accordingly.  More information can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx).